# JavaScript/JQuery --> Run function anew each time I click corresponding to that function link

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to run function anew (so that counter runs from 0 to specified number) each time I click corresponding to that function link ?

As for now the problem is that it works only on the first click.

https://jsfiddle.net/mtxg3ez2/56/

This is how I conncected 2 links with 2 different function names so that it fires : When I click the given link (there are 2 links) I store its data attribute inside variable and fire the function whose name matches that stored data attribute string.

Function:

HTML:

```
<a href="" data="one">one</a>

<a href="" data="two">two</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var storedata = $(this).attr('data');

    jQuery('.canvaswrap').fadeIn();

  console.log(storedata)
  window[storedata]();


});


window.one = function() {
     setInterval(progressSim , 40); 

}

window.two = function() {

     setInterval(progressSim2 , 40); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would `clearTimeout` in `progressSim()` and `progressSim2()`, however `sim` and `sim2` are undefined.

So you should assign the setInterval to a variable like:

```
var sim;
var sim2;
window.one = function() {
    sim = setInterval(progressSim , 40); 
}
window.two = function() {
    sim2 = setInterval(progressSim2 , 40); 
}
```

And reset the number to zero in

```
if (al >= 94) {
  al = 0; // reset the number
  clearTimeout(sim);
}
```

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
var ctx2 = document.getElementById('my_canvas2').getContext('2d');
var al = 0;
var start = 4.72;
var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
var diff;

var greenPart = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100);
greenPart.addColorStop(0, '#0f2596');
greenPart.addColorStop(1, '#0ea5e8');

var whitePart = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100);
whitePart.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
whitePart.addColorStop(1, '#0e97df');

var width = 3;
var width2 = 1;

ctx2.save();
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.rect(-width, -width, 70 + width, 70 + width * 2);
ctx2.clip();
// Then we draw the left half

ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.arc(35, 35, 45, 0, Math.PI * 4, false);
ctx2.fillStyle = '#fff';
ctx2.fill();

ctx2.restore();

// This is the First Function 

function progressSim() {
  diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);

  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#1c295c';

  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.font = "bold 19px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .54, ch * .54 + 2, cw);

  // First we make a clipping region for the left half
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(-width2, -width2, 100, 100 + width2 * 2);
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.lineWidth = width2;
  // Then we draw the left half
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#d7ecf6";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, 0, Math.PI * 4, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default

  // Then we make a clipping region for the right half
  ctx.save();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(50, -width, 50 + width, 100 + width * 2);
  ctx.clip();
  // Then we draw the right half
  ctx.strokeStyle = greenPart;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, 4.78, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default
  // First we make a clipping region for the left half
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(-width, -width, 50 + width, 100 + width * 2);
  ctx.clip();

  // Then we draw the left half
  ctx.strokeStyle = whitePart;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default
  if (al >= 94) {
    al = 0; // reset the number
    clearTimeout(sim);
    // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
  }
  al++;
}

// This is the Second Function 

function progressSim2() {
  diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);

  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#1c295c';

  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.font = "bold 19px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .54, ch * .54 + 2, cw);

  // First we make a clipping region for the left half
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(-width2, -width2, 100, 100 + width2 * 2);
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.lineWidth = width2;
  // Then we draw the left half
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#d7ecf6";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, 0, Math.PI * 4, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default

  // Then we make a clipping region for the right half
  ctx.save();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(50, -width, 50 + width, 100 + width * 2);
  ctx.clip();
  // Then we draw the right half
  ctx.strokeStyle = greenPart;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, 4.78, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default
  // First we make a clipping region for the left half
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(-width, -width, 50 + width, 100 + width * 2);
  ctx.clip();

  // Then we draw the left half
  ctx.strokeStyle = whitePart;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore(); // restore clipping region to default
  if (al >= 54) {
    al = 0; // reset the number
    clearTimeout(sim2);
    // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
  }
  al++;
}


$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var storedata = $(this).attr('data');
  jQuery('.canvaswrap').fadeIn();
  console.log(storedata)
  window[storedata]();
});
var sim;
var sim2;

window.one = function() {
  sim = setInterval(progressSim, 40);
}

window.two = function() {
  sim2 = setInterval(progressSim2, 40);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 30px;
  color: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" data="one">one</a>
<a href="" data="two">two</a>
<div class="canvaswrap">
  <canvas id="my_canvas2" width="70" height="70"></canvas>
  <canvas id="my_canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: try to click fast 2 or more times on the given link, it picks up speed :P

Comment: So you have to clear both setInterval and reset the number when you clicked on `one` and `two`.

Comment: Something like so https://jsfiddle.net/c4khk69f/10/

Dude thank you for your effort :)

Comment: Yes. Glad it helps.